# Delete book from iBooks Mac when I delete it from iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, books, contacts

I sync "All books" from my iOS device (an iPod Touch) and my Mac, in iBooks.

When I delete a book in iOS, it is NOT deleted on my Mac. Instead, in iTunes, the setting changes from sync "All books" to sync "Selected books", with the deleted books unselected.

Instead, I want to keep it to "All books", and delete books I delete on my iOS device to also delete on my Mac.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately that's not possible.** iCloud will auto-download books to Mac-any book you buy on your iPod will pop up on your Mac, and vice-versa. But no, you can't auto-delete books on Mac every time you do so on iPod.

However, you *can hide your iCloud-stored titles from appearing on the iBooks shelf.*

1. Select the "All Books" drop-down.

[image]

2. Swipe the "Hide iCloud Books" thing.

[image]

You'll end up with this. The shelf's empty because I haven't downloaded any book yet. Redo steps 1 and 2 to make it reappear.

[image]

On the Mac, go to iBooks' settings to do the same.

Comment: The first paragraph (I think) assumes that certain settings are made.  I have bought things on the iPad that are NOT on my MacBook Pro.  Yet other things have duplicates on the MacBook.  And some things on the MacBook don't appear on the iTunes list as available to sync.  Extremely irritating.